# Debian to OpenSuse

Tags: ubuntu, debian, opensuse, suse

I am a Debian User for long. However I've an wish to have a taste of OpenSuse too. But the most Important thing to know is. In Debian or any Debian based distros, problem of Broken Dependencies / Dependency hell are less common, But What about Suse ? Is it same too ? or yast is not that good as compared with apt-get. I've never used any rpm based distro. So How hard its gonna be for me ? and also whats the alternative of `pppoeconf` on suse or any other rpm based distro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Debian's .debs and .rpms as far as technology goes is pretty much Pepsi vs. Coke - i.e. almost none. YaST resolves dependencies for you just like apt-get does.

I believe what you are looking for is rp-pppoe (http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse/rp-pppoe.html)

Comment: I'd go a step further and say that YaST is *better* than apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from debian, you will find the zypper commandline tool more similar to apt-get/aptitude than the yast software installer.

Dependency hell is not that common in opensuse. You usually use repositories from the Open Build Service (https://build.opensuse.org) which include all dependencies for your specific distribution version.

You can configure your PPPoE connection through the Yast Network Management module.